# Gob decode cannot decode interface after register type

Tags: go, methods, interface, gob

I have these types defined:

```
func init() {
    gob.RegisterName("MyMessageHeader", MyMessageHeader{})
    gob.RegisterName("OtherMsg", OtherMsg{})
}

//
// Messages
//

type MyMessageHeader struct {
    MessageId InstanceIdType
    OtherId   uint64
}

type MyMessage interface {
    Id() *MyMessageHeader
}

type otherStruct struct {
    X uint8
    Y uint8
}
type OtherMsg struct {
    MyMessageHeader
    OtherField *otherStruct
}


func (m *OtherMsg) Id() *MyMessageHeader {
    return &m.MyMessageHeader
}

func MarshalMessage(m MyMessage) ([]byte, error) {
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&buff)
    if err := encoder.Encode(&m); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Newf("Could not marshal message: %v", err)
    }
    return buff.Bytes(), nil
}

func UnmarshalMessage(buf []byte) (MyMessage, error) {
    var msg MyMessage
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(buf))
    if err := decoder.Decode(&msg); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Newf("Could not decode my message: %v", err)
    }
    return msg, nil
}
```

When I try to use `UnmarshalMessage` I got the error `gob: OtherMsg is not assignable to type MyMessage`. 
I have no difference with the usage in the [go examples](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#example__interface) for encoding and decoding an interface. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have time to test it right now, but I suspect you may want to register your `package.OtherStruct` also in the `init()` function.

Comment: @AndrewF, good idea!, sadly it wasn't because of that. Ill update the question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message says:

> gob: OtherMsg is not assignable to type MyMessage

Which is true. `MyMessage` is an interface which requires implemener types to have a method:

```
Id() *MyMessageHeader
```

A value of type `OtherMsg` does not have such method in its [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets), only a pointer to it, that is a value of type `*OtherMsg` (because `OtherMsg.Id()` has pointer receiver).

To make it work, register a value of type `*OtherMsg`:

```
gob.RegisterName("OtherMsg", &OtherMsg{})
```

Or simply:

```
gob.Register(&OtherMsg{})
```

See a working example on the Go Playground:

```
func init() {
    gob.Register(&OtherMsg{})
}

func main() {
    var m MyMessage = &OtherMsg{
        MyMessageHeader: MyMessageHeader{
            MessageId: 1,
            OtherId:   2,
        },
        OtherField: "othervalue",
    }

    data, err := MarshalMessage(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    m2, err := UnmarshalMessage(data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m2)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lTfGmA7z-9f)):

```
&{MyMessageHeader:{MessageId:1 OtherId:2} OtherField:othervalue}
```